# Why does mapply() behave differently depending on the function called?

Tags: r, mapply

I am hoping someone can help me understand why the `mapply` function behaves differently when you call the `sum` function and when you call the `mean` function.

My question is probably better explained by looking at this MWE (partly borrowed from https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/a-brief-introduction-to-apply-in-r/)

```
l1 <- list(a = c(1:10), b = c(11:20))
l2 <- list(c = c(21:30), d = c(31:40))

mapply(sum, l1$a, l1$b, l2$c, l2$d)

[1]  64  68  72  76  80  84  88  92  96 100
```

The above code returns 10 values, the sum of the corresponding elements in each object a, b, c and d.

The following example does not work in the same manner:

```
mapply(mean, l1$a, l1$b, l2$c, l2$d)

[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

In the latter example it seems like b, c and d are being ignored and it is just calculating the mean of each element of a.

If someone could help me understand this that would be great.

Many thanks!

Comment: This has little to do with `mapply`. See `?sum` and `?mean`: they have a different mechanism in dealing with their arguments. What do you think `sum(1,2,3)` will return? And what about `mean(1,2,3)`?

Comment: Thank you nicola, the penny has finally dropped now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mapply` works as expected. It sums or means element-wise from lists of elements. For example:

```
l1$a[1] + l1$b[1] + l2$c[1] + l2$d[1]

[1] 64

mean(l1$a[1], l1$b[1], l2$c[1], l2$d[1])

[1] 1
```

Note that `mean` only uses the first argument because it only accepts `x` (see `?mean`).

```
> mean(l1$a[1])
[1] 1
> mean(l1$a[1], l1$b[1])
[1] 1
```

You may want to use `rapply`.

```
l <- list(l1, l2)
rapply(l, mean)

   a    b    c    d 
 5.5 15.5 25.5 35.5
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So am I right to say that the reason `mapply` didn't work as I expected is because the `mean` function only allows one argument of number(s) whereas the `sum` or `range` functions will take multiple single numeric arguments?

Comment: @Frost_Maggot exactly. Definitions are `mean(x, ...)` where `...` are arguments passed from and to other methods whereas `sum(..., na.rm = FALSE)` where `...` are vectors.